# Nginx - How to redirect dropping a character from URL

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have Old URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/board/here-is-the-title-t1234.html
```

I want the above to be forwarded to New URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/forum/here-is-the-title-1234
```

I need to do the following using the regex in Nginx:

1) Drop the .html

2) Remove the 't' character that is together with the number (that always appears last before html extension).

This is what I have now:

```
rewrite ^/board/(.*)\.html$ http://example.com/forum/$1 permanent;
```

With the above, I am able to drop .html part but having a hard time trying to achieve (2) - Dropping the character 't' that is together with the number.

**I want `t1234` to become 1234 in the urls where `1234` can be any number.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
rewrite ^/board/(.*)t(\d+)\.html$ http://example.com/forum/$1$2 permanent;
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vL3nE0/1)

Comment: PERFECT! That worked. Thank you so much :) I do have a question on that rewrite and sorry if this sounds dumb - is it wrong to have the integer part as `(.*)` instead of `(\d+)`?

Comment: Got it... `\d` is a character class to match digits whereas `(.*)` matches everything. Makes sense now. Thank you so much @arco44. I will accept this answer in 5 mins when it allows me to. :)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I did now. Had to wait few minutes since arco444 was too quick :)